# How to delete the rows in DataSet table and make it reflect in the database using SQL DataAdapter?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am executing `row.Delete()` and `dataAdapter.Update(dataset, "mytable")`

I have specified delete command as well for data adapter.

But the deleted rows are not getting deleted in the database.

Am I missing anything? Insert and update are working.

I donot want to use `CommandBuilder`.

Comment: The AcceptChanges method is called automatically when calling the update methods of a TableAdapter or data adapter.

Comment: @Suresh where is the delete command you have specified, will be good to have it here think that is the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup you're dataAdapter.DeleteCommand? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.deletecommand.aspx)- this is the command that will be fired for each row in the DataTable that has been deleted.

Might be the cause.